# Netty ProxyHandler for HTTP/2

Tags: proxy, netty, http2

I am using [Netty](https://github.com/netty/netty) as a client-server framework for the development of Java network applications.

Does **Netty ProxyHandler** supports **HTTP/2** ? If so, from which version it is supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the ProxyHandler does only support HTTP1/1.